# Can Not install available update

Tags: updates, libav

i can't check to install this available update 
here is my problem about my ubuntu:

[image]

i have tried it from terminal with sudo apt-get update, but it still unsolved

[image]

Comment: can you post the errors you got,along with the question. If you are behind a proxy, you need to have a apt.conf file in /etc/apt with your uname and password along with the pxoy details.give more details.

Comment: What happens when you tick an item in the update manager?

Answer (score 5):

It's caused by those files requiring other files to be installed/removed in order to be installed, but Ubuntu doesn't allow this by default.

To fix this you should run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

I had this issue earlier, and it resolved itself automatically one day for some reason. :/